# Get div contents where contents matches a string

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, jquery-selectors

I have a couple of DIV's:

```
<div> bob </div>
<div> dog </div>
<div> total_10 </div>
<div> rat </div>
```

Is there a way to get the div with jquery which contains the string "**total_**". The purpose is to retrieve the value after that which is **10**. Also the div's don't have any classes or id's.

The result would be somethinh like:

```
var total = $(SELECTOR).html; //which is 10
```

Thanks so much ;)

Comment: where are you stuck? No try on your side???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If only one DIV:

```
var total = $('div:contains(total_)').text().split('_').pop();// 10
```

You could wish to trim value or get a number instead of a string:

```
var total = +$('div:contains(total_)').text().split('_').pop();
```

Comment: There are a number of assumptions here.  For example, this assumes, as @a-wolff stated, that there is only one div that matches.  It also assumes there is only one underscore and everything after it is your number.  And it assumes no other div will ever contain the text "total_" unless it is the div you are trying to extract. Consider this when settling on an implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the `:contains` selector:

```
$("div:contains('total_')")
```

Comment: var total = $("div:contains('total_')").text().replace('total_', '');

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery you have the contains selector http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/ This selector select all elements that contain the specified text.

So in your case you should use:

```
$("div:contains('total_')");
```

Comment: Ok, so why is everybody downvoting?

Comment: I provide the documentation link and an explanation instead of just drop in a line of code and got 3 downvotes without any reason provided.

Answer (score 0):

Try [:contains()](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)

```
$('div:contains(total_)').text().match(/\d+/g);
```

<kbd>[**fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/jTpDX/)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('div').each(function(){

  if($(this).text().contains('total_')){
     return $(this).text().replace('total_','');
  }
  return 0;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You following code:

```
var total = $("[id^='total_']").html()
```